# Setting NLS_SORT variable for a single select only

Tags: sql, oracle

Good day,

my customer uses an application that was initially designed for MSSQL, which is probably doing case-insensitive searches by default. But the customer uses Oracle and hence, needs some extra tweaking.

So the question is: How can I tell Oracle to make a given SELECT LIKE-Statement search case-insensitive with the following limitations?

- ALTER SESSION cannot be used individually (by trigger: maybe)
- Other queries from the same session must not be affected
- The SELECT-statement cannot be altered

I know about the possibility to set NLS_SORT on system level, but this will basically kill the performance, as all indexes are disabled.

Comment: If you can't change the select statement, presumably you can't modify the application to set and reset the session either side of it being called? A login trigger could change NLS for the whole session but you've ruled that out. Are the search terms always fixed case - either entirely upper or lower? If so is using a view in front of the table(s) a possibility?

Comment: Hi Alex, yes this would be a solution, if it doesn't affect inserts and updates

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DBMS_ADVANCED_REWRITE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_advrwr.htm#ARPLS083) to rewrite the SQL into a case-insensitive version.

Subtly changing queries like this can be confusing and can make troubleshooting and tuning difficult.  The package also has some limitations that may make it impractical, such as not supporting bind variables.

**1. Sample Schema**

```
SQL> drop table test1;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table test1(a varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test1 values ('case INSENSITIVE');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

**2. The query is initially case-sensitive and matches 0 rows**

```
SQL> select count(*) total from test1 where a like '%case insensitive%';

     TOTAL
----------
         0
```

**3. Create rewrite equivalence - add a `LOWER` function**

```
SQL> begin
  2     sys.dbms_advanced_rewrite.declare_rewrite_equivalence(
  3             name             => 'case_insensitive_1',
  4             source_stmt      => q'[select count(*) total from test1 where a like '%case insensitive%']',
  5             destination_stmt => q'[select count(*) total from test1 where lower(a) like '%case insensitive%']',
  6             validate         => false
  7     );
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**4. Now the same query is case-insensitive and matches 1 row**

```
SQL> alter session set query_rewrite_integrity = trusted;

Session altered.

SQL> select count(*) total from test1 where a like '%case insensitive%';

     TOTAL
----------
         1
```